# Is $U$: open $\implies$ $f^{-1}(U)$ different from $f(U)$: open $\implies$ $U$: open?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then the following result is famous:

$$
U (\subseteq \mathbb{R}): \text{open} \implies f^{-1}(U): \text{open}
$$

However is this different from the next statement?

$$
f(V) (\subseteq \mathbb{R}): \text{open} \implies V: \text{open}
$$

Comment: It is different. Consider $f(x) = 1$ (constant function). Then the first result gives $f^{-1}(U) = \mathbb R$ for any open set $U$ containing $1$. But the second result misses this: the only open subset of $\mathbb R$ of the form $f(V)$ is $\emptyset$.

Comment: To get the difference, try $f(x)=x^2$ and $V=[-2,-1]\cup(0,3)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's different.

Consider the function $f(x)= x^2$, which is continuous, and thus has the first property.

Now $f(\{-1\} \cup (0,2) )= (0,4)$, is open, while $\{-1\} \cup (0,2)$ is not.

Comment: The key here is that $f$ is not injective!

Comment: Yes. Just as you said it I was thinking I should have added that.

Comment: Thanks, I can make such a counterexample for any non-injective continuous functions

Comment: @myuuuuun I am not sure if your comment is an assertion or a question. I agree that this should be possible. But maybe it needs some work.

Comment: @quid It's just an assertion. I'll try to prove it by myself, thanks.

Comment: note: if f is additionally injective, then the 2nd statement holds. By the 1st statement, $f(U): \text{open}  \implies f^{−1}(f(U)): \text{open}$. Since $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and injective, f is actually bijective(strictly increasing or decreasing). Hence $ f^{−1}(f(U))=U$ and this completes the proof

Comment: note: and even if f is not injective, there exists some functions that the 2nd statement holds. Let f be a constant function. As @Bungo discussed above,  $f(V)$ is open only if $f(V) = \emptyset$. Then $V=\emptyset$ and this is open.

Comment: @myuuuuun thanks for the observations, especially the second comment. However, a continuous injective function is not necessarily bijective. Consider $e^x$ for example, which is injective but not surjetive. The "hence" is still true though

Comment: @quid you're right, it's not bijective, thanks!